# Codeigniter duplicate content with mod_rewrite

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter, duplicate-content

In codeigniter, once you enable short urls, you have the possibility of duplicate content because although your new URLs look like:

http://domain.com/privacy_policy

You can still manually access the old links, which still load when you type in:

http://domain.com/index.php/privacy_policy

My htaccess file, per the manual, looks like:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

What should I do to solve this problem?

Comment: you have to remove index.php from url permanently so pages can not access using index.php .
check this link for how to remove index.php from url in codeigniter
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14783666/codeigniter-htaccess-and-url-rewrite-issues/14807463#14807463

Comment: @RahulChipad No idea about what you say. Even if you remove the index.php page from the url, you still can access the original address because of `RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php)` or `%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` rule, as the OP mentioned. Check my answer instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could resolve this issue by redirecting the user agents to a new URL.

### Method #1: Using htaccess

Use the following just after `RewriteBase /`, as the first RewriteRule:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} index\.php
RewriteRule ^index.php(?:/(.*))?$ $1 [R=301,L]
```

You might want to change `$1` to `http://example.com/$1` if you haven't used `RewriteBase`.

The other rules **MUST** come after the above rule.

### Method #2: Handle with PHP

I'd suggest to [extend the `CI_Controller`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21147262/how-to-put-data-from-a-controller-into-a-specfic-div-element-in-a-view/21149592#21149592) as follows:

```php
class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        // Execute CI_Controller Constructor
        parent::__construct();

        // Get the index page filename from config.php
        // For perior to PHP 5.3 use the old syntax.
        $index = index_page() ?: 'index.php';

        // Whether the 'index.php' exists in the URI
        if (FALSE !== strpos($this->input->server('REQUEST_URI', TRUE), $index))
        {
            // Redirect to the new address
            // Use 301 for permanent redirection (useful for search engines)
            redirect($this->uri->uri_string(), 'location'/*, 301*/);
        }
    }
}
```

---

However, the search engines **won't index** the URLs which look like `index.php/privacy_policy`, **Unless you've used** such URL addresses in your page.

Also, you could use a **[canonical link element](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_link_element)** within your pages to [make search engines **index only one** version](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/139394?hl=en) of the page for their search results:

```
<link rel="canonical" href="http://domain.com/privacy_policy">
```

Particularly in CodeIgniter:

```
<link rel="canonical" href="<?php echo base_url(uri_string()); ?>">
```

Answer (score 1):

On `config/config.php`, remove `index.php` on `$config['index_page']`

```
$config['index_page'] = '';
```